# How to change placeholder color React Native RNPickerSelect

Tags: react-native

I am using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select

I've tried multiple methods to change the color of the `RNPickerSelect` placeholder text. But none of them have worked.

Tried the following ways:

```js
style = {
  {
    inputIOS: {color: Constants.colour.black},
    inputAndroid: {color: Constants.colour.black},
    placeholderColor: Constants.colour.grey_90,
  }
}
```

```
placeholder = { 
  label: placeholderText, 
  value: null, 
  color: Constants.colour.grey_90 
};
```

**UPDATE:**

For Android you should set placeholder color in the style proportie like this, hope i can help someone :) :

```
    style={{
            placeholder: {color: Constants.colour.grey_50},
            inputIOS: { color: Constants.colour.black },
            inputAndroid: { color: Constants.colour.black },
          }}
```

Comment: Yout update is so helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will suggest you to always look in the issue board in the github repository of a package at first if there is no example in the package homepage. You might have found a solution there.
In this issue you will get your answer https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/100 .

Here is the example code:

```
            <RNPickerSelect
                placeholder={{
                    label: 'Select a color...',
                    value: null,
                }}
                placeholderTextColor="red"
                items={this.state.items}
                onValueChange={(value) => {
                    this.setState({
                        favColor: value,
                    });
                }}
                onUpArrow={() => {
                    this.inputRefs.name.focus();
                }}
                onDownArrow={() => {
                    this.inputRefs.picker2.togglePicker();
                }}
                style={{ ...pickerSelectStyles }}
                value={this.state.favColor}
                ref={(el) => {
                    this.inputRefs.picker = el;
                }}
            />
```

Comment: Sure... and true. But everyone loves googling and finding a nice answer like this on StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't work with the latest version (8.0.1, October 2020).

One needs to set

```
placeholder: {
  color: 'red',
}
```

in the `style` parameter, see
https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select/issues/100#issuecomment-622469759

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i used:

```
const pickerStyle = {
    inputIOS: {
        color: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
    placeholder: {
        color: 'white',
      },
    inputAndroid: {
        color: 'white',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
};

return (<RNPickerSelect style={pickerStyle} ... />)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
style={{
        placeholder: {
           color: 'red',
         },
       }}
```